# Is this BaseBeen anti-pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, anti-patterns

I have an utility library with the class ConsoleApp, which has only static method like GetIntValue(string name) to ask user to enter the integer value of the parameter with specified name, or functions to parse command line parameters.

As for me ConsoleApp is an utility class, and inheriting it just to get avoid "ConsoleApp." in the code looks like BaseBeen anti-pattern.

But on the other side, ConsoleApp will be inherited only by the classes that is really Console applications, in this way, it's not a BaseBeen.

So, is it really BaseBeen?

Comment: That method being static is already dubious.

Comment: A bit of code would go a long ways

Answer (score 1):

SOLID design principles (particularly SRP, O/CP, and DIP) suggest that you're *better* providing that functionality via delegation (e.g. strategy pattern). Has-A is better than Is-A, etc.

However, you're pretty squarely in first-world-problems territory here because Program.cs is very much on the transient end of your codebase. Clearly you might need to parse some command line parameters before your bootstrapper runs (e.g. to configure your bootstrapper!), so you might find it challenging to inject some kind of value provider.

So, I'd say *yes it's an antipattern*, however *there are probably more important things to worry about*.

See e.g. http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0145.pdf page 8 where Uncle Bob talks about DIP:-

> "Main is the most concrete of our
>   functions and it will create all of our instances and all of the
>   factories ... and it will then
>   hand off to the abstract part ... and  the
>   abstract core will manipulate it as though it were  in this fantasy
>   world where everything was abstract."

If Main has to call some static methods, that's ok. If you want to inherit from a utility class to make it easier for you, that maybe smells a bit but I don't really care. Just make sure you know where the boundary is. If you're using your static utility class outside of Main then you're likely to have a problem.